# Spring MVC: How to distinct controller request and resource request

Tags: spring-mvc, event-listener

I have an event listener which source code like:

```
@EventListener
public void handleEvent(ServletRequestHandledEvent event) { ... }
```

However, I not only capture the controller request but also capture JS / CSS request, would I know how to distinct them?

Answer (score 0):

If your JS/CSS requests are starting with `/css` / `/js` (i.e. `/js/app.js`, `/css/styles.css`) you can distinct them by checking the `URL`. Access it with `event.getRequestUrl()` and do the proper matching on strings (i.e. `url.startsWith("/css")`).

Or override the `public boolean supports(Object handler)` method in `SimpleServletHandlerAdapter` and do a check on `((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean() instanceof YourController`